# Second countable space implies numerable subbasis

Tags: general-topology, second-countable

If a topological space (X,t) has a numerable basis, implies X has a numerable subbasis?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Any basis is also a subbasis

Comment: A base is a subbase trivially, and a countable subbase implies a countable base. So the notions are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**  Any basis for a topology is also a subbasis for that topology.